# How to run thread after completing some specific worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I created two swing worker thread class in my swing application. They are load thread, save thread

1. Load thread is used to load the data from rest service
2. Save thread is used to push the data to rest service.

My question is that,

- How to execute my threads one by one when i create more instance for
  load thread?
- Save thread should be run after completing process of existing load
  thread

Does any one guide me to get solution for this scenario?

Note: I am using Swing Worker class to call rest services.

Comment: Have you thought of using thread.join() ??

Comment: Let the load thread schedule a `Runnable`(for pushing) in some executor service once it is done with the loading.

Comment: Hi ortang. I got your point. Can i execute executor with FixedThreadPool size as one?

Answer (score 0):

You should start your save thread in the `done` method of your load thread. 
You can pass your saveThread to the loadThread as constructor argument or define it as class member.

This should work for you;

```
   SaveThread mySaveThread = new SaveThread();
   LoadThread myLoadThread = new LoadThread();

   class LoadThread extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
       @Override
       public String doInBackground() {
           //do your work 
           return "";
       }

       @Override
       protected void done() {
           try { 
               mySaveThread.execute();
           } catch (Exception ignore) {
           }
       }
   }

   myLoadThread .execute();
```

Comment: I can't call save thread automatically because it will be call when user wants to save by clicking button

Comment: If you will call the save thread when user clicks the save button, then you make the button enabled in the done method of load thread above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load data from multiple threads, and save this data from one thread after ALL data will be loaded. You can try to use barriers. For example [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) can wait while all load threads finished their works.